Why can't I integrate right away here?
I have two equations:
$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=(\frac{dx}{dt})^2$ if x = 0
and $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$ when t = 0 and I need to solve for x and t.
I know the answer involves using both the equations but I'm confused why we can't just use $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$ and get an answer like so:
$$\int_0^xdx=\int_0^tdt$$
$$x=t$$

you have a differential equation in terms of $\frac {dy}{dx}$ and an initial condition in terms of $\frac {dx}{dt}$  That is a little bit unusual.  Are you sure you have transcribed it correctly?

Yeah you're right. Sorry!

The condition $dx/dt=1$ is only given at the boundary $t=0.$ Your solution rests on the assumption (not given in the problem statement) that $dx/dt=1$ for all values of $t.$
